# TeX4ht and Plain TeX

Tags: plain-tex, tex4ht

According to [tug.org](http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-commands.html#QQ1-9-45) TeX4ht can be used with Plain TeX. I've tried the commands listed in the site above, but nothing works! All I can have is a simple text file, with `.html` extension, but without any HTML tag.

What is the correct way to convert a Plain TeX file into HTML?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Hello @egreg!. Nice to meet you here.

Comment: Let's try and see if someone here is able to help.

Comment: Hmm, htlatex is working as expected. Maybe some bug?

Comment: @someonr: I don't know what htlatex is. As you can read in the link I enclosed, and as I said three times in my message (once in the title), I was speaking about **Plain** TeX. Thanks for your comment anyway.

Comment: Sry, I just was thinking this might be helpful because `htlatex` and `httex` are just some wrappers scripts for `tex4ht` and `t4ht`. (main difference is that one is using `latex` and the other is using `tex`)

Answer (score 7):

**edit:**
I've created simple package for `Plain` support in `tex4ht`. Basically it defines commands needed by `tex4ht` to insert basic document hooks:

```
% file plain-4ht.tex
\def\documentstyle#1{}
\documentstyle{tex4ht}
\csname tex4ht\endcsname
\def\document{}
\def\enddocument{\csname bye\endcsname}
```

Now you can just use:

```
\input plain-4ht.tex
\document

Some text.
\enddocument
```

What is still a issue is support for accented characters.

---

*Original post*:

According to [CVR's blog](http://www.cvr.cc/plain-tex-and-tex4ht/), you need to enclose your document with these commands:

```
\input amstex
 \documentstyle{amsppt}
 \csname tex4ht\endcsname
 \document

 . . . source of your plain TeX document . . .

 \enddocument
```

and compile with

```
httex file "xhtml,html4.4ht,unicode.4ht,mathml.4ht"
```

Following sample works for me:

```
 \input amstex
 \documentstyle{amsppt}
 \csname tex4ht\endcsname
 \document

{\bf What} about the {\it formatting}

The quadratic formula is $-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} \over 2a$

P\v{r}\'ili\v{s} \v{z}lu\v{t}ou\v{c}k\'y ku\v{n} \'up\v{e}l \v{d}\'abelsk\'e \'ody
 \enddocument\bye
```

I am not plain TeX user and don't know what is the plain version of the inputenc, so instead of utf-8 characters I used control sequences for the diacritics.