# Is there a Software to convert TeX to LaTeX?

Tags: conversion, mathml

Is there a software to convert TeX to LaTeX? I have a file that needs to be converted into MathML in order to convert it to HTML and some of this files are in a TeX format.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you explain what you want to do? Do you want to convert TeX to LaTeX?

Comment: No, there is no such converter. However, it is easy to use a TeX document with `latex`

Comment: @Kurt: You can use `htlatex filename.tex "xhtml,mathml"` to get the `HTML` output with `MathML` format.

Comment: you can convert plain to html directly with tex4ht, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40017/2891

Comment: tex4ht, mathjax and most other tex to mathml convertors will read plain tex math.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "a" TeX format? That could be plain, eplain, lollipop, ConTeXt, ...