# make4ht for plain tex

Tags: plain-tex, html, make4ht

I want to convert a plain tex document to html using **make4ht**. If I use this command line `make4ht document.tex` the program calls the compiler "latex" and blocks the compilation. The `make4ht --help` command does not explain how to compile the plain tex.

What is the exact command line to compile a plain tex to html document?

Comment: perhaps this can help https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40017/2388.

Answer (score 7):

It is not so straightforward to get TeX4ht working with Plain TeX. Ulrike already pointed to my [older answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40017/2388). We can use that as a starting point. Save the following code as `plain-4ht.tex`:

```
% file plain-4ht.tex
% the following macro needs to be executed in order to include all .4ht files
\csname tex4ht\endcsname
```

I've simplified the code to the bare minimum. The `\csname tex4ht\endcsname` command needs to be executed in order to insert the basic HTML structure.

This file just needs to be inserted after all macro definitions:

```
\input plain-4ht

Hello world
\bye
```

The next issue is how to actually execute plain TeX using `make4ht`. We need to use a build file for that. Save the following file as `mybuild.lua`:

```
Make:add("httex", 
'${htlatex} --interaction=${interaction} ${latex_par}' ..
"'\\def\\Link#1.a.b.c.{\\expandafter\\def\\csname tex4ht\\endcsname{\\expandafter\\def\\csname tex4ht\\endcsname{#1,html}\\input tex4ht.sty }}" ..
"\\def\\HCode{\\futurelet\\HCode\\HChar}\\def\\HChar{\\ifx\"\\HCode\\def\\HCode\"##1\"{\\Link##1}\\expandafter\\HCode\\else\\expandafter\\Link\\fi}" ..
"\\HCode ${tex4ht_sty_par}.a.b.c.\\input \"\\detokenize{${tex_file}}\"'", 
{htlatex="dviluatex"})
Make:httex {}
```

It uses the `Make:add` command to create new command `Make:httex` which executes Plain TeX. The used engine can be configured using `htlatex` parameter (the default engine is `htlatex="dviluatex"`)

You can compile the document using

```
make4ht -e mybuild.lua filename.tex
```

The last issue is how to configure your custom macros. TeX4ht can load configuration files for particular files thanks to patched `\usepackage` command, but it doesn't work in Plain.

Let's say that you have a file `mymacros.tex`:

```
\def\mytitle#1{\bgroup\bf #1\egroup\par}
```

We want to use the `<h1>` element for `\mytitle` in the HTML document. Create file `mymacros.4ht`:

```
\NewConfigure{mytitle}{2}
\def\mytitle#1{\a:mytitle#1\b:mytitle\par}

\Configure{mytitle}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<h1>}}{\HCode{</h1>}}
```

A sample document:

```
\input mymacros
\input plain-4ht

\mytitle{My title}

Some text.

\bye
```

The `mymacros.4ht` file can be included in the `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\catcode`\:=11
\input mymacros.4ht
\catcode`\:=12
\EndPreamble
```

We need to use correct catcodes as `:` characters are used in the `.4ht` files. This is all done automatically in LaTeX.

You can now compile the document using:

```
 make4ht -e mybuild.lua -c config.cfg filename.tex
```

This is the result:

[image]

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
<head>

<title>sample.html</title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta name='generator' content='TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)' /> 
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' /> 
<link rel='stylesheet' href='sample.css' type='text/css' /> 
<meta name='src' content='sample.tex' /> 
</head><body>
<h1>My title</h1>
<!-- l. 6 --><p class='indent'>    Some text.

</p>    

</body> 
</html>
```